# Can ASP.NET MVC html helpers render an element without an ID attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Assume I want to generate an element similar to this in ASP.NET MVC 2:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FooBar)%>
```

**Is there an overload or way I can get ASP.NET MVC 2 to only generate a name attribute and not an ID attribute?**

I can have it generate a blank id with `<%= Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FooBar, new { id = "" })%>`, but I would like to generate the element with no ID at all, and without overriding the asp.net mvc framework.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The behavior of the HTML helpers was changed as of MVC 2 RC1 so that passing `new { id = "" }` suppresses *id* entirely rather than outputting an empty *id* attribute.