# Generating an MVC3 RadioButton list in a loop statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, loops, razor, radiobuttonfor

A collegaue of mine created a model and here it is.

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public class ModifyCollegeListModel
{
    public List<SchoolModel> CollegeList { get; set; }
    public List<SchoolListModel> SchoolList { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int QuestionnaireId { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SchoolModel
{
    public Guid SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? ApplicationStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

I intend to create a loop that will generate the radiobutton list for the ApplicationStatusId , something like this...

**Razor Code**

```
   @foreach (SchoolModel justright in Model.CollegeList.Where(m => m.CategoryId == 3).OrderBy(m => m.SchoolName).ToList<SchoolModel>())
    {
        <tr class="@HtmlHelpers.WriteIf(eventCounter % 2 == 0, "even", "odd")">
                <td class="school"><b>@justright.SchoolName</b></td>
                <td class="location"><b>@justright.StateName</b></td>
            <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => justright.SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.DidNotApply)</label></td>
            <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => justright.SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.Accepted)</label></td>
            <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => justright.SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.NotAccepted)</label></td>
        </tr>

    }
```

but what happens is that ALL radiobhuttons created has the same name so they are grouped as one giant radiobutton collection. not via the schoolID... *scratches head*

Can someone help me here and point me to the right direction on how i will be able to create radio buttons that are grouped per row?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801401/asp-net-mvc2-radio-button-generates-duplicate-html-id-s) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291975/html-radiobutton-of-asp-net-mvc-generates-id-and-name-same), this might help

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things.

First up, I would remove the filtering logic from the view. What I mean is this part:

```
Model.CollegeList.Where(m => m.CategoryId == 3).OrderBy(m => m.SchoolName).ToList<SchoolModel>()
```

That sort of logic belongs in a service. Also it will make the view much cleaner.

Secondly, I think you'll need to use a for-loop so MVC binds everything back how you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollegeList.Count; i++) {
    <tr class="@HtmlHelpers.WriteIf(eventCounter % 2 == 0, "even", "odd")">
        <td class="school"><b>@CollegeList[i].SchoolName</b></td>
        <td class="location"><b>@CollegeList[i].StateName</b></td>
        <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.CollegeList[i].SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.DidNotApply)</label></td>
        <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.CollegeList[i].SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.Accepted)</label></td>
        <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.CollegeList[i].SchoolId, (int)BrightHorizons.CC.BusinessLogic.CollegeListApplicationStatusEnum.NotAccepted)</label></td>
    </tr>
}
```

You'll notice after using the for-loop, that the radiobutton names and ID's also contain their index in the CollegeList. For example:

```
<input id="CollegeList_0__SchoolId" name="CollegeList[0].SchoolId" type="radio" value="2">
```