# MVC3 Passing dictionary<string,bool> from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I need to display a few checkbox on a form and the user can check as many as hey want.

So I store the checkbox options on Database. (required)

Model

```
public class Options
{
    public int OptionsId {get; set;}
    public string Option {get; set;}
}
```

On the viewModel,

```
IEnumerable<Options> listCheckBoxOptions {get; set;}// store list of options from database
Dictionary<string,bool> checkboxs {get; set;} // store if is check or not
```

So on the view i want to store the check box value (true/false) in this checkboxs dictionary.

```
@foreach (var x in Model.listCheckBoxOptions)
     {                  
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkboxs[x.Option])
           @m.Option <br />                             
     }
```

So when i submit the form... the checkboxs is null when gets to the controller.

Any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand: the view is correctly presented, but when you post it you're losing the checkboxes values?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 checkbox on the view which is created by the foreach loop. So if i check two of the box and post to the controller. when i check the checkboxs variable on the controller it is null.(nothing at all)  basically i want the controller to get it like this checkboxs[Option1] = true, checkboxs[Option2] = false , checkboxs[Option3] = true. Depending on which checkbox the user check. I believe, it has to do on how i format the html so i think it has to do with the foreach loop in which generates the html for the checkboxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboxes will be given names like this `checkboxs[key here]` and ID's like this `checkboxs_key_here_`. MVC doesn't know how to bind these back.

Have a look at this thread that I answered just days ago: [Generating an MVC3 RadioButton list in a loop statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839111/generating-an-mvc3-radiobutton-list-in-a-loop-statement/11839242#11839242)

It's the same thing, just using RadioButtons instead of CheckBoxes.

Comment: Radio buttons don't allow for multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Editor Template**

Add one more property to your ViewModel. For Better Readability, I am going to change the name from plural to singular (**Options** to **Option**)

```
public class Option
{
    public int OptionId {get; set;}
    public string Option {get; set;}
    public bool IsSelected { set;get;}
}
```

And your Main ViewModel,

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Option> OptionList { set;get;}
  public CustomerViewModel()
  {
     OptionList=new List<Option>();
  }
}
```

Create a View called `Option.cshtml` under `Views/YourControllerName` folder.

Have this content inside that.

```
@model Option
@{
   Layout = null;
}
<p>
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsSelected, Model.Option)
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OptionId)
</p>
```

And in the Main form, Call it like this

```
@model YourViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{     
   @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.OptionList)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now in your `POST` action, you can check the `IsSelected` property value of items in the `OptionList` property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel model)
{
   foreach(var opt in model.OptionList)
   {
      //check for model.IsSelected value for each item
   }
}
```